# Having some issues with shared libraries

Tags: c++, c

I am compiling a program for source, and it is not finding some dynamic libraries that are compiled with it. Here is the output when I run the executable. (It compiles fine)

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libipeqtcanvas.so.7.0.14
  Referenced from: /Users/zrbecker/testipe/bin/./ipe
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap
```

My question is, I know -L finds libraries while compiling, but how do I make sure the program can find the libraries when running.

The libraries are located at the relative path ../lib from the executable which is in a bin directory.

Comment: The compilation process creates an executable that has all information about libraries. That much it gets during compilation itself. So, if you were to create the executable on a computer that had the libraries in the path you mention, everything should run just fine. However, taking that binary and running it elsewhere (where the libraries are not available) may be a problem.

Comment: C or C++? Pick one. It actually sounds like neither have anything to do with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (or actually, `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, since you're on OS X) at runtime to include the library directory.

`export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/lib"`

Comment: Awesome this works, but is there a way to handle it at compile time?

Comment: Just an addition. I am trying to package everything inside of an App bundle, so the libraries are going to be inside of the bundle and potentially moved around.

Comment: I think you can include `@executable_path` in a path to refer to the run-time path of an executable.